# Typescript - Record of keys on an object with its value being a keyof the type of its value

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following and I want to create an object that has the same keys but where its value must be a transformed version of the value of the key in the original type.

```
export type CCDTypes = {
  AuthorisationCaseEvent: AuthorisationCaseEvent,
  AuthorisationCaseField: AuthorisationCaseField,
  CaseEvent: CaseEvent,
  CaseEventToFields: CaseEventToField,
  CaseField: CaseField,
  EventToComplexTypes: EventToComplexType,
  Scrubbed: Scrubbed
}
```

at the moment I can achieve that manually with

```
export type COMPOUND_KEYS = {
  AuthorisationCaseEvent: (keyof (AuthorisationCaseEvent))[],
  AuthorisationCaseField: (keyof (AuthorisationCaseField))[],
  CaseEvent: (keyof (CaseEvent))[],
  CaseEventToFields: (keyof (CaseEventToField))[],
  CaseField: (keyof (CaseField))[],
  EventToComplexTypes: (keyof (EventToComplexType))[],
  Scrubbed: (keyof (Scrubbed))[],
}
```

but I want COMPOUND_KEYS to be tied to CCDTypes for the type safety. When more CCDTypes are added in the future I would like typescript to complain if the data has not been added to COMPOUND_KEYS.

I intend to do a couple of other transformations like this, hence my want to create this base type CCDType type

I've tried something along the lines of the following:

```
Record<keyof(CCDTypes), (keyof(keyof(CCDTypes)))[]>
```

but the second type here ends up wanting keys that exist on an array (which makes sense since `keyof(CCDTypes)` returns an array.

How can I declare this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom mapped type:

```
type AllObjectKeys<T> = {
    [P in  keyof T]: Array<keyof T[P]>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA8gIwFYQMbANIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAWACgomoBtABSgEsA7JgazwB7AGZRiAXQBcsAE4yAhiEICQIse3GkGAXwYNQkWAFdgAC0EzO+ecE6DuAYXn4IAUQBuEbsEo0GzKHlpfGBLbgBzHX1waBgTc0trW3snFwAxTgg4ABNfOkZmZGDQnkj6XXoIAA8wCx8DaAcHABFiGPw8-2MzCysbO0dnN09vaTiexP6UoY8vYAAaLvGEvuTB9MycsfjepIHUiAys7MXyvUqauqgGqAdEAFk2RABVADlmgH1sVwBNAGVfPAkGhMDg8EQmq12qQgA)

Comment: Works great thanks! How can I take this a level deeper with creating a type with ALL keys from ALL values on this object? Something like `{ [K in keyof T[P in keyof T]]: any}`

Comment: @user3494322 this should work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmBBANmgPAFQHxQF4psoIAPYCAOwBMBnYqAfigGt4B7JYgLiiogA3CACcAsAChQkKOjQIARgCsIAY2BwQdHPiIBvSVCNQA2gAUoASypHNyOThPsQXYgF1cbvgEMqISQC+kpLS0CgArsAAFhwilnTewJYcVADC3nQQAKLCVMCEUAYSxlDefHTAcVQA5oEh4GGRMXEJSSnpmQBilhBoNAVFJQrllda1EkES5GCx+aFQqakAItgNDPqGsk2x8YnJaRnZucB8EdE7rfsdR9TAADSbZ827bQddPX2n2y177YfdvRoDwmwSmZBmIjmDQWCAAsmYEABVABySwA+jAsgBNADKBTkihU6k02kWKzWuCAA

Comment: Is it possible to make the type of each key the actual type instead of any? ie, in the playground link, we know that "a" and "b" are strings, but when creating an object of this type, it'll allow "any"

Comment: @user3494322 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmBBANmgPAFQHxQF4psoIAPYCAOwBMBnYqAfigGt4B7JYgLiiogA3CACcAsAChQkKAFUqASw5UAagEM0AVwg4ANLFIVq9KAAURHSCNBwQ+IiXKVaDAEoQAxhxE1MMfQpUSKJQKrgsKnwCwiIA3JLS0OhoCABGAFaewLZ0OPZQAN6SUCVQANqmUIEltsjJOGXsIFzEALq4rXzySqoa2g1NLdit+qa4kgC+kgngSZrAABbeCnRqwD0Awmp0EACiwlTAhIXFpWpRmgC2qaKTMzIo80siK2ub2xAAYgoQaDTHRQkpSgqT4dGALyoAHM7hJyGBvEdElANhsACLYWYMIiAkqPRbLVbrZRbHb7ajAPj456vYlUUl7A7AXSnamEt4kj7fX40KlPdl0hncv4siRTCSSeGIqDIjYIACypgQsgAcmiAPowXYATQAysdkmlMh5svBcqiMVjcEA